# Hibernate- Getting one record will all null values from database

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get data using hibernate. My query is correct but record for particular id does not exist it still returns one record (return list size is 1) with all `null` values.

Below is part of code:

```
org.hibernate.SQLQuery query = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
List<?> resultList = query.list();  // resultList size is one having all null values but size should be zero
```

The `sqlQuery` I am trying is below:

```
SELECT SUM(table1.column1=1) as column1, 
    SUM(table1.column2=1) as column2, 
    SUM(table1.column3=1) as column3 
FROM table1 
    RIGHT JOIN table2 
      ON table1.unitid =table2.id 
    RIGHT JOIN  groupsunits 
      ON table1.unitid =groupsunits.unitid 
where table2.status = 'active' and groupsunits.group_id=415
```

Please share your suggestions for this issue.

Comment: Can you post sqlQuery & are you querying against view or table; does it contain pk.

Comment: @NayanWadekar Please find query in my post

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve with this query? The reason you see this is that `SUM` is defined to return `NULL` when summing over an empty set. Your solution depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @mabi I am trying to use conditional sum on particular column for records. Do sum of column values if only column value is 1 else skip that record. I am using this query along with required joins on tables.

Comment: So what you actually want is a `COUNT` of rows that satisfy a specific property ("have `column1 = 1`")?